# Can we make a wormhole inside another wormhole?

Tags: science-based, physics, wormholes

### The Setting

Let's make an imaginary machine powered by the sheer will of argument. Let's call it a cosmic anti-mass sowing machine, cause why the heck not. (If you can't tell, I don't expect this to work.) This machine could magically pluck wormholes out of cosmic foam, think [Kurzgezagts example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9P6rdqiybaw) of how to make one.

What if we had a spherical, three dimensional wormhole, instead of my ideal square-shaped 2D hole in spacetime that I tried to brand the "phase-gate" machine.

### The Question

Let's say we make a wormhole... between two far-off places, let's say between Jupiter and Saturn and its equivalent point around some far off star, Proxima Centauri. We then built a magic armature around the wormhole to prop it open, and expand it to the size of earth, with a throat 10 meters long. As far as my understanding of wormholes goes, the space in the middle of the wormhole is just that, regular old empty space, just like the empty space out between the stars.

If this wormhole is big enough that tidal forces don't matter too much, what happens if we bring this cosmic sowing machine into the middle of the wormhole, pretending that this machine is the size of a standard earth sowing machine.

What happens if we turn it on and make a new pair of wormholes? And then we tow them out and expand them? Could we make more wormholes, inside of a wormhole? Is there a rule against this? And are they somehow related to the wormhole they were created in, so that if it were to be destroyed, it will cut all wormholes threaded through?

### The Why

Basically, the point of this is that if we were to transport a single wormhole off to a different star system, if we wanted another wormhole, say, as a backup incase someone were to destroy the original, do we have to transport it sub-light or can we make a new one inside of the old one and drag the ends out?

And if so, then if the old one is destroyed, is the new one also destroyed?

Comment: Given that any sort of wormhole is solidly in the realm of sufficiently advanced magic, you can have wormholes within wormholes in your world if you wish. They can behave however you want them to. How do you expect there to be a single specific answer to a question that is effectively about magic?

Comment: Related: [What are the casualties from the "Bonehead Manouver"?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/221092/what-are-the-casualties-from-the-bonehead-maneuver) - On our Sci-Fi stack, referencing Babylon 5).

Comment: @sphennings there is math behind wormholes, but I assume someone here knows the answer. I would try to find a satisfactory answer, but when I use the word wormhole, I get a whole lot of sensational news articles about how we are a few years out from building one in our backyards. *GRRR**

Comment: Conventions in fiction are set (and changed) by writers - if you say it can work, who are most of your audience to disagree. Are you expecting letters of outrage from physics professors? Just say that in your world, the *type* of wormhole you're making allows it if you want it.

Comment: @AngryMuppet I was rather cynical in this post because I feel guilty hand-waving a pivotal piece of plot, when I discuss antimatter propulsion and fuel generation in this book, and science-backed terraforming and lots of other things that I put time into making plausible, I feel it being out of place to have **literally no explanation** for how these supposed phase-gates worked. Sure, the expanse got away with it cus its ancient aliens, but in this book, humanity figures it out.

Comment: But if all else fails, then I can just use some technobabble about directing virtual particles and whatnot for negative mass, and some massive energy-release to punch a hole in spacetime, and stabilize it into a magic interstellar doorway for spaceships.

Comment: What is there to gain by explaining it? You and your audience don't understand the real world math behind wormholes. The genre convention of wormholes don't follow the real world math anyway. Any explanation will necessarily be a handwave. The more you wave your hands the more you draw attention to it. If you just say, "wormhole travel exists in my world, it follows these rules" you've minimized the area with which people can poke holes. You can't find fault with the explanation if there isn't one.

Comment: Well I guess... I didn't specify but part of the book revolves around a stranded crew on a far-flung ocean world, with a destroyed phase-gate in orbit, which they have to repair in order to go home, and expose some criminal syndicate thats manipulating world governments and their clandestine experiments on this ocean world.

Comment: So I do need to at least say what it is they are replacing in order to fix the machine, but I can always just have something **other** than the wormhole machine, like the dyson sphere that powers it, be destroyed.

Comment: None of that is dependent on your phase-thingy following real world physics. You just need to make them internally consistent. What you're probably looking for is convincing sounding technobabble which is purely an aesthetic choice.

Comment: @sphennings, good point, I will take your advise when I'm working on my book! If I need any advice, are you ok with my asking you?

Comment: The answer to this falls under the heading of "making up an answer is more interesting than finding the one true answer." Can you pass the mouth of a wormhole through another wormhole? Sure, why not? If you do so, does the second wormhole continue to pass through, and be dependent upon, the first wormhole? Go with the rule of cool. Nobody is going to call you on it, since wormholes themselves are just theoretical.

Comment: @RobertRapplean ok!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer more-or-less boils down to "it depends". The thing it depends upon is the nature of your [wormhole metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solutions_of_the_Einstein_field_equations), and the [magic unobtanium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wormhole#Raychaudhuri%27s_theorem_and_exotic_matter) you use to wedge the throat of the wormhole open and make it traversable.

For example, Orion's Arm, which put [quite a bit more thought into its wormhole physics](https://www.orionsarm.com/fm_store/Wormhole_Engineering_Overview.pdf) than it did with some other aspects of the setting, gives the answer "no". This is in part because their wormholes have mass, and mass interferes with the magical fields that prop the wormhole open. If you put too much mass too close to the throat of the wormhole, the wormhole collapses into a black hole because the magical force is no longer sufficient to do the job. If you try to push a tiny wormhole through a big wormhole, then the tiny one gets squished.

If *your* flavor of wormhole was somehow massless, you still have to deal with the spacetime distortions that are naturally induced by the [negative space wedgie](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NegativeSpaceWedgie) that holds the wormhole open... there will be all sorts of interesting tidal effects that similarly risk disrupting one or other of the wormholes involved.

So, yeah. The only person who can really answer your question is *you*, because the nature of *your* wormholes is defined by the constraints of *your* setting and story. There are no real-world wormholes, only theories and papers with varying degrees of plausibility and controversy. Orion's Arm style crunchy physics imposes constraints you may or may not want in your world (eg. you can only have a wormhole [*tree*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)), not a fully connected network) and if you want something different you'll be needing a different kind of wormhole and unless you're intending to do a PhD in applications of spacetime-torturing (which might interfere with the actual story-writing thing) you may as well just wave your hands and decide for yourself how you want your space magic to work.

Comment: Thanks! Gees! The first proper answer to all my questions! Thank you! And in the end I think Ill wave my hands and make a magic doorway that I never explicitly say is a **wormhole**, so that I don't have to deal with all the strange physics and focus on  making the drama and romance more interesting. ^-^

Comment: I will take your advice when I'm working on my book! If I do need some more advice, are you ok with my asking you?

Answer (score 7):

The space within a wormhole isn't fundamentally different from the space outside of a wormhole, it's just connected to the surrounding space in a different way. The throat of a wormhole, if spatially "flat" enough for spacecraft to travel through said wormhole, seems as good a place as any to put the end of another wormhole.

And the "throat" of a wormhole doesn't pass through the flat space between its ends "outside" the wormhole, it provides an alternate route. In principle, there is no difference between transporting one end through flat space to a distant destination, or transporting it through an existing wormhole to that destination. Whether that wormhole continues to exist shouldn't affect the wormholes that have been transported through it, unless they're actually something rather different from wormholes as described by current theory.

Of course, actual wormhole engineering may involve keeping them as far away from each other as possible to keep them from exploding. Alternatively, perhaps existing wormholes are a required part of the process of creating new ones, and you need access to a wormhole just to create a new one.

Answer (score 7):

**Crap... people have started answering your question**

There are some serious problems with your question. Unfortunately, the moment someone answers it, deleting it is no longer an option.

- *Remember for future reference!!! You are allowed one and only one question per post. Asking two or more questions is **literally** a reason to close a question. (VTC:Needs More Focus is specifically defined as "asking more than one question.") Thus, I'm only answering one question.*

But that is the least of your problems.

**There is no such thing as a 2D wormhole**

The pretty picture people are used to seeing, like the one below courtesy [Science News](https://www.sciencenews.org/article/black-hole-circling-wormhole-weird-gravitational-waves) (click to enlarge), is a simplified representation to help the general public comprehend the concept. That's because visualizing a 3D hole in space is *almost* as hard as visualizing a 4D cube.

[image]

Which leads people to think that traveling through a wormhole looks something like this (image courtesy [Live Science](https://www.livescience.com/building-a-wormhole-with-cosmic-strings.html), go read the article, it's pretty interesting):

[image]

Yeah. That's not what happens. The reality is that all wormholes (if they exist) are 3D and have spherical entry/exit points.<sup>0</sup> 3D universe, 3D wormholes. QED.

**Which means the trivial answer to your question is "no"**

It's no because there isn't a throat. Remember, that pretty 2D graph is showing you *space-time.* That visualization that looks like there's space to put something else *doesn't exist* because you, the traveler, *must always be on the plane of the graphic,* even in this simplified representation. There is no throat.

**But does that mean you can't have some worldbuilding fun in your universe?**

Why not! From the perspective of (*ahem...*) *real space* (if anyone knows what that really is...), there's a sphere somewhere near our solar system and a sphere somewhere near Alpha Centauri and the "distance" between the spheres is less than the real-space distance (light years) between the two stars.<sup>1</sup>

But what happens if you have two spheres in our local system *that happen to be right on top of each other?<sup>2</sup>*

Let's be outrageous and inconvenient. Let's use *spherical coordinates* with the center of our sun as (0°,0°,0) with one "zero degree" axis perpendicular to the galactic plane and the other a "meridian" drawn from the center of our Sun to the center of the galaxy. That ought to cause the celestial mechanics hobbyists to bust a vein.

So, both wormhole entrances are located at (0°, 45°, 5AU).<sup>3</sup> One wormhole connects to Alpha Centauri and the other connects to Betelgeuse. In your world, if you enter either sphere at Alpha Centauri or Betelgeuse, you appear a short time later here at Sol.

**World rule: what happens when someone enters the sphere at Sol?**

- We admit that as yet undiscovered and undefined tidal forces (see footnote #2) tear your ship into curiously compressed strips.

But that's *boring!* Reality, even theoretical reality, is so overrated.

- Or we leave it up to quantum fate. You have a 50%/50% chance of appearing at one destination or the other.

But that's not exactly practical. On the other hand, you *could* set a rule that makes it practical.

- If you enter one hemisphere, you end up at one destination. Enter the other hemisphere, end up at the other destination. This also determines what happens if you exit the Sol sphere. One hemisphere or the other.
- If you rotate the ship along its approach vector clockwise, you end up at one location, rotate anti-clockwise takes you to the other.
- If you enter at one velocity (energy level) you get to one destination, at another velocity (energy level), you go to the other.<sup>4</sup>

Etc.

*In other words, you don't need to take "no" for the answer. You can step away from "science" (since we can't prove wormholes are real anyway) and set rules that, frankly, would be a pretty cool way of establishing wormhole travel for a civilization that can make them. It's no different from defining how time travel works.*

---

<sub><sup>0</sup> *It's been 30 years since I last looked at wormhole theory with any significant concentration, but if I recall correctly, even the idea of "distance" when traveling through the wormhole really isn't expected to be true. Those two spheres, the "entrance" and "exit" are coincident in space-time. In other words, there aren't two spheres, there's one, and you can see it in two locations in spacetime due to the "fold." When you enter a sphere at Sol you are simultaneously exiting the same sphere at Alpha Centauri. No throat. There is no throat. Those 2D pictures have really been a disservice to people. (But I could be wrong....)*</sub>

<sub><sup>1</sup> *That statement will not only make celestial machinists howl, it'll make angels weep and devils laugh (read Footnote #0 after all). Wormhole travel is unlikely to be anything like what we saw on* Star Trek: Deep Space 9, *much less* Stargate. *It's represented better in* Intergalactic, *but it's still only guess work. Besides, what's the real value of wormholes when time from the perspective of your parents back on Earth slows for you as you approach light speed? Really, it's only that they're still alive when you arrive at your destination. It's no difference at all to you. And that statement might make physicists howl and all those angels cry again. Oh, well. In for a penny....*</sub>

<sub><sup>2</sup> *And we're going to ignore what we think (and probably will be) the space-shattering universe-ending implications of two wormhole termini sitting one on top of the other. Personally, methinks it's a bit like trying to force the north poles of two really powerful magnets to sit together. You can crush a Buick doing things like that, dontchaknow.*</sub>

<sub><sup>3</sup> *If that didn't make you roll your eyes and snort a quick burst of laughter, I can't help you.*</sub>

<sub><sup>4</sup> *Said energy levels might even be used to rationalize how you created two coincident wormhole termini, which is obviously a benefit because too many wormhole termini litters local space, making navigation a real pain in the neck. Besides, you never know what's going to happen when all those stellar winds come romping through those wormholes and hit our poor, defenseless sun.*</sub>

Comment: Firstly, fantastic answer! Thank you! Secondly, your *how old?* Are you a physics professor somewhere?

Comment: I've only just jumped a year ahead of my peers and am getting into high school. Thirdly, I think that one-question-per-post thing needs some sort of clause for when you ask a question so related to the main one that its pointless to make a **second** post to answer it. I.E. How big of an explosion would 1Kg of antimatter make and what would it look like?

Comment: I'm 55 and I'm an electrical engineer who happened to really like astronomy back when life gives one more time. Please take my answer with a grain of salt. We have some real physicists here who may correct what I've said.

Comment: Unfortunately, the one question rule is Stack Exchange's, not ours. We can't modify it.

Comment: Well done. Have you read The Quantum Magician? The author talks a lot about rotating in axises that don't exist in the real world while inside a worm hole. The unfortunate real math-based answer is that wormhole entrances are singularities. You'd need to do *something* to open one wide enough to pass things through. That something might allow you to move a singularity through it just like it allows you to move the ship through. That something probably involves more dimensions than we know what to do with.

Comment: [Not all wormholes are spherically symmetric.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/388500/do-polyhedral-wormholes-make-sense) Is there a reason you discount the possibility of wormholes having non-zero throat length? There are problems, such as tidal distortion during transit, with spherical wormholes of that type, problems that are alleviated with throat length. Throat length also acts as a buffer against CTC formation which helps in the case of threading one wormhole through another.

Comment: @RobertRapplean I haven't! But that sounds like it has real possibilities for a story. Regrettably, my available time is much less than I wish it was.

Comment: @BMF Remember footnote #0. It's been 30 years since I put any real time into wormhole theory - so things getting discounted reflects my age more than intent. But the important part of my statement was "wormhole *theory."* We can't speak of them as if any of them actually exist (yet...). Your linked SE post and its answer posit things like cubical wormholes. That's not how nature works - but then again, the OP here is talking about manufactured wormholes. Nevertheless, I'm required to defer to anyone who's better read on the subject than I.

Comment: **Concerning the word "throat..."** As a note to everyone, please be aware that the word "throat" has two meanings in the OP's question and in my answer. I should have avoided that. Definition #1 is, when referring to the traditional 2D graph, the volume at the top of the funnel, which doesn't actually exist. It's an artifact of the simplification that leads to an erroneous conclusion. Definition #2 is the passage between the entrance and exit of a wormhole. But that passage is always (insofar as I understand wormholes) *inside* the wormhole. Please keep those two definitions in mind. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe "throat" is a misleading term, but there IS a space in between the 2 ends of the wormholes. A finite 3d volume of 3d space. And the only way to leave this space is through one of the ends of the wormhole. For me personally, "throat" if perfectly fine to describe this space.

Comment: @JBH Ahh, understood. That's not how nature works *naturally*, but I've seen a few polyhedral thin-shell wormholes that may be easier to construct, need less negative stress-energy, have almost negligible mass, and have next to no tidal stress during transit. On the face of it they sound ridiculous, but are still very attractive options, if feasible.

Comment: The famous paper by Morris and Thorne considered spherically symmetric wormholes because it's mathematically simple, not because it's the only possible shape or even the most plausible shape. See [this answer](//physics.stackexchange.com/a/732231). And wormholes can have a throat, even the spherically symmetric ones. You seem to have the idea that the funnel shape in that 2D embedding diagram has no higher-dimensional counterpart, but it does. Nothing is fundamentally different in the higher-dimensional case.

Comment: @benrg That's interesting, but we're still dealing with nothing more than mathematics. I'm an engineer. A mathematically valid solution doesn't reflect reality until proven to do so. Nevertheless, the foundation of that answer would be the foundation of a good answer to this question, on behalf of an OP who only needs suspension of disbelief.

Comment: I'm not going to chime in about the wormhole stuff, but you are using _spherical coordinates_, not _polar coordinates_, since it's 3D.

Comment: @ArthurDent Now THAT is a very good point. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, my serious attempt at an answer:

"Possibly"

Here is my reasoning - if we assume that a Wormhole is the result of bending spacetime, then it stands to reason that we could also bend spacetime in such a way that would allow this to happen...

But! I think that there would be severe limitations on the end-point of such a secondary wormhole.

If we imagine the classic piece of paper demonstration (y'know, where you fold it over) - in the process of folding once - no problem, but if we now try and fold that piece of paper again *our options for folding it become exponentially smaller with each fold* and some options aren't possible if we want to maintain the original wormhole.

just a single additional fold could potentially severe the original wormhole or could drastically alter it's properties.

As such, for most practical scenarios - it is better and more efficient to create a single wormhole, travel through it, then create another.

In addition - even using in-universe Maths and Science, it is incredibly difficult to predict what locations within a wormhole have which valid end-points - leaving it in the realm of high-risk (I'm presuming that this is part of the story - a Main character uses this strategy for great effect).

Answer (score 2):

## Sure

To really picture a wormhole, fold a piece of paper and stab a pencil through it. Don’t bring the paper all the way together. That way, you have your travel distance. Now, fold the paper again, and stab it with something sharp enough to puncture a pencil. Now the resulting creation you have is called a wormhole to inside of a wormhole.

Theoretically, you can just keep <strike>stabbing things</strike> opening wormholes into the <strike>pencil</strike> wormhole, until there physically is no more space. (But you can always open wormholes into those wormholes into those wormholes, etc.)

If said <strike>pencil</strike> was destroyed, your wormholes would lose their anchor point and “snap” back to their other anchor point. (Pull a rubber band really far back and then let go for a demonstration.) Said wormholes to wormholes would also “snap back”.

That all said, this is back of the envelope work done based on stabbing pencils through sheets of paper. <strike>If this gets accepted, you owe me a new set pencils and paper</strike>

Comment: That wouldn't so much be a wormhole inside a wormhole as it would be a complex wormhole with 4 endpoints, since you can travel from any 1 endpoint to any of the other 3 endpoints. That's not how a wormhole inside a wormhole would work: each wormhole end is connected to exactly 1 other wormhole end.

Answer (score 0):

### Yes, no problem

JBH sounds confident about the dimensionality thing, but they didn't extend the metaphor far enough.

Imagine you're a 2D entity in a universe that's a 3D sphere. You can only access, and conceptualize, the sphere's surface. Your planet is a 2D circle and you walk on its 1D perimeter, knowing only up, down, forward, and backward.

If you traveled far enough in space, you'd get back to where you started. And if there were a hole through space, you could get to some other point faster; in this case space is a torus rather than a sphere. You still never go "through" the *center* of the hole like a 3D object would; you hug its edges, remaining embedded in the 2D surface.

This of course means you can enter the hole from any direction and still come out the other side (specifically, the direction you enter affects the direction you leave).

Inside the wormhole, you can travel perpendicular to its length and quickly wrap around the tube, ending up where you started. Some conceptions make this distance so small you can't really move at all, but you said there's space in there, so all that means is that the tube is wide enough to move around in (again, around its circumference, not through its center).

Then if the walls of the wormhole have area, you can just as easily punch another hole through that and come out somewhere else on the surface of the main sphere.

[image: A crude MS Paint drawing of a pair of wormholes forming a sort of T shape inside a sphere]

Everything above applies equally to a 3D universe embedded in a 4D sphere. From there, extrapolate from a sphere to a weird potato or intricate coral structure or whatever you want it to be, and throw out any bounds on distance, because more dimensions solve that problem, as easily as you can make any parts of a 1D string touch without really stretching anything.

So now you should be able to see what would happen if the first wormhole was destroyed. You'd probably have to close both ends individually to really cut off access via the sub-wormhole! Whatever holes remain might snap back into a slicker shape, including the ends becoming flat again… or maybe you decide you want dead-end wormholes to be a thing? Could someone get trapped in there if both ends get closed off? Are there loads of old wormholes or naturally-occurring pocket universes floating around in there? Lots of possibilities!

Comment: That was a little confusing, but useful! For one I think I'll rip off the expanses flat wormhole gate thingies that never get explained properly, it's simpler and no one cared that much ^ ^. I still want to talk realistic wormholes in short stories, because I love writing them, but the point of the question was wether or not you could pull the end of a wormhole through another wormhole.

Comment: But this also applies sort of. On the off chance that you do, is there a rule forbidding pulling the mouth of one wormhole through another? Like if you have wormhole A at Earth and B at Centauri, could you make a new wormhole pair (C and D) and leave C at earth while moving D to Centauri through the A-B wormhole? (A-B is a wormhole and C-D is a second wormhole)

Comment: @SamKitsune Ah, so wormholes are usually created by physically moving their ends the long way around? Interesting. In that case I don't see why you couldn't also move it along the wall of another wormhole and out the other side.

Comment: Exactly. The thing is that wormholes can be suspended as subatomic pairs in antimatter-trap-like machines (in universe) but I wandered if you transported a wormhole to a different star, if you wanted communication wormholes also, do you also need to move them sub-light, or just move the end through the already-present wormhole.